# May I have a Vim session report its "Mode" in its "Window Title"?

Tags: command-line, visual-mode, insert-mode, normal-mode, startup

### Clarification of the moving parts

First, let me clarify what I mean by "Window Title", and what I expect to achieve

- On Windows OS, GUI programs will have three attributes: its Window Title texts, the process.exe name and its win-class name. An example of Gvim ran through Xming looks like the following: 
  [image]

  - **Window Title**: `[No Name] - - GVIM1`
  - win-class name: `Xming X`
  - Process Name: `Xming.exe`
- I am looking for a way to **start** Vim, so that:

  - Instead of reporting `FileName -- GVIM1` as its "Win-Title", it also reports, either:
  - `Filename -- GVIM1 - Insert-mode` OR `Filename -- GVIM1 - Normal-mode`, depending on the current state of Vim.

Please advise if there is a better way to have Vim dynamically update its "Title".

### Explanation

At the end of the day, I would like to detect the precise Vim mode through its "Window Title". This opens new doors for re-mapping indistinguishable pairs of keys, like `<tab>` and `<c-i>`.

For example, through AutoHotKey, which runs on Windows OS, I can happily assign `<tab>` (in normal mode) to a particular command-line function, while keeping `<c-i>` behaving "normally" (go to the next position on the jump list). AutoHotKey detects WinTitle by default and will need a lot more effort to conduct real-time OCR on the dynamic Window of Gvim, to tell its current mode. Blindly remapping the `<tab>` key will distort the *normal usage* of `<tab>` key in Insert-mode.

Please advise if this is achievable, as it is funny to learn that `<tab>` and `<c-i>` are identical keys in the year 2019 :)

### Motivation and cross-reference (TL;DR)

Things start from [this post about Vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/607), where I re-learned that `<c-i>` and `<tab>` are indistinguishable by the Modern Vim. This brings conflict in my hard-to-change muscle memory. For the mappings in normal mode:

- `<c-i>` should take me to the more recent position in the jump list (opposite of `<c-o>`), and
- `<tab>` should handle its own business:

  - For Vimwiki, `<tab>` jumps to the next hyperlink, and `<s-tab>` jumps to the previous hyperlink
  - For other filetypes, I do not press `<tab>` key in normal mode.

I tend to spend a considerable amount of time in Markdown documents, and I rely on [Vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) to nativage the stacks of Markdown files. (I maintain two websites + one personal wiki with more than 2,000 entires.)

At the end of the day, I would like to "split" the functionality of `<tab>` and `<c-i>` ==> In Normal-mode, pressing `<tab>` shall issue `:VimwikiNextLink<CR>` and `<c-i>` shall bring me to the next point in the Jump list.

Since it is well established that `<tab>` and `<c-i>` are treated alike by Vim, I am planning to use AutoHotKey to *overwrite* the `<tab>` key **only in Normal Mode**. This is where all dots should connect: through a title-matching trick in AutoHotKey, `<tab>` is only mapped to `:VimwikiNextLink<CR>` in normal mode.

Given the tweak on the `titlestring` option, I see the light of distinguishing modes.

Comment: Why would reporting vim's mode in the window title have any effect on whether or not you can remap `<tab>` and `<C-i>` separately? I don't know what you're trying to do, but this seems really convoluted. It's probably going to be simpler to pick a different mapping, or maybe use an `<expr>` mapping. (Also for the record,  tab and `C-i` are indistinguishable because they're literally the same ASCII value, 0x09)

Comment: Here goes my rationale: should a third-party hotkey manager (AutoHotKey) tell the precise Vim-mode, it can "overwrite" the `<tab>` key in normal mode, and leave `<c-i>` untouched. Thus, the two keys are then distinguished. Let me update my original post for the missing motivation piece.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, for now, the missing piece is to indicate whether Vim enters command-line-mode through the `titlestring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

`:set titlestring=%F\ %{v:servername}\ %{mode()}`

this will indicate the mode as `n` rsp. `i` and some other characters as described in `:help mode()`

You can improve the last expression (`%{mode()}`) to something longer using a ?: construct.

Comment: This is fantastic! May I ask how to deal with the visual block? (Just curious). Otherwise, the single character `i` and `n` should be telling enough for me to identify the vim-modes through the title line :)

Comment: Update to the previous comment ==> This is fantastic! One more question: can Vim tell its title that the "active cursor" is at the command line? I am almost there :) It turns out that when I enter the Vim-command-line through `:`, nothing at the title changes

Comment: Seems like mode() does not support indicating being in command-line-mode

Comment: Actually, mode() does support it. However it looks like for whatever reason, Vim does not update the title for entering command mode.