# May I let `titlestring` tell whether I am in command-line mode?

Tags: vimscript

Following from [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/may-i-have-a-vim-session-report-its-mode-in-its-window-title), I can happily "project" character `n` to the `titlestring` when Vim is in Normal-mode, and "project" character `i` to the `titlestring` when Vim is in Insert-mode. This almost finished my journey of having external programs to learn about Vim's precise mode.

**Question**: may I add an indicator (character) to the `titlestring`, so that it reflects the status when Vim enters the "command-line mode", via pressing the `:` key?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, it looks like Vim does not update the title when entering command line mode. There might be a hack, involving `au CmdlineEnter *` but I have no clue what command to call, that would force an update to the titlestring

Comment: Pointer to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647093/3925312